# How to change the appearance of an anchor (text) by comparing 2 id?

Tags: html, jquery, css, anchor

I'm building a book-like pagination style for my website. It is composed of a 4 parts code: the text supposed to be displayed, the pages numbered, the "next" and "previous" buttons and the script to determine which part/page of the text is displayed.

```js
var current = 1;
var totalPages = document.getElementById("pageContainer").childElementCount;

function showPages(id = 1) {
  if (id < 1 || id > totalPages) 
    return;
  curr_page = document.getElementById("page" + current);
  curr_page.classList.add("pageHidden");
  curr_page.classList.remove("pageDisplayed");

  target_page = document.getElementById("page" + id);
  target_page.classList.add("pageDisplayed");
  target_page.classList.remove("pageHidden");
  current = id;
}
```

```css
 
.pageHidden 
{
 display: none;
}

.pageDisplayed 
{
 display: block;
}
```

```html
   
<div id="pageContainer">
 <div class="pageDisplayed" id="page1"><p>page 1 displayed</p></div>
 <div class="pageHidden" id="page2"><p>That is the second page.</p></div>
 <div class="pageHidden" id="page3"><p>And finally a third one.</p></div>

</div>



          <h2>pages : 
 <a href="#" id="1" onclick="showPages(1)">1</a>
 <a href="#" id="2" onclick="showPages(2)">2</a>
 <a href="#" id="3" onclick="showPages(3)">3</a>
          </h2>
    
      
      
    
<h2>
  <span style="float: left;">
    <a href="#" onclick="showPages(current - 1)">Previous</a>
  </span>

  <span style="float: right;">
    <a href="#" onclick="showPages(current + 1)">Next</a>
  </span>
</h2>
```

Now, I'd like to mark the actual page that is being displayed by changing the appearance of the link. For now it shows
"Pages: 1 2 3"
And I'd like it to become, for example:
"Pages: 1 [2] 3" (with a different color for the marked "[2]".

I've found ways to do that, but I couldn't make it works with the "next" and "previous" button, which, when triggered, didn't highlight the anchor number.

Basically, if the function showPages returns "page2", the anchor "2" with the id "2" should appear like that: [2].

I think it means that I have to compare the id from the page container, to the id from the pagination part... Anyone know how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same As you are hiding previous block and showing new block. create a css class with following css:

```
.page:before{
  content: '['
}

.page:after{
  content: ']'
}
```

this css will wrap any element with page class in brackets [].

Now add page class to selected page and remove from older one.

```
  pageNum = document.getElementById("" + id);
  pageNum.classList.add("page")

  pageNum = document.getElementById("" + current);
  pageNum.classList.remove("page")
```

Here is your working code.

```js
var current = 1;
var totalPages = document.getElementById("pageContainer").childElementCount;

function showPages(id = 1) {
  if (id < 1 || id > totalPages) 
    return;
  curr_page = document.getElementById("page" + current);
  curr_page.classList.add("pageHidden");
  curr_page.classList.remove("pageDisplayed");

  target_page = document.getElementById("page" + id);
  target_page.classList.add("pageDisplayed");
  target_page.classList.remove("pageHidden");

  pageNum = document.getElementById("" + id);
  pageNum.classList.add("page")
  
  pageNum = document.getElementById("" + current);
  pageNum.classList.remove("page")
  current = id;
}
```

```css
.pageHidden 
{
 display: none;
}

.pageDisplayed 
{
 display: block;
}

.page:before{
  content: '['
}

.page:after{
  content: ']'
}
```

```html
<div id="pageContainer">
 <div class="pageDisplayed" id="page1"><p>page 1 displayed</p></div>
 <div class="pageHidden" id="page2"><p>That is the second page.</p></div>
 <div class="pageHidden" id="page3"><p>And finally a third one.</p></div>

</div>



          <h2>pages : 
 <a href="#" class="page" id="1" onclick="showPages(1)">1</a>
 <a href="#" id="2" onclick="showPages(2)">2</a>
 <a href="#" id="3" onclick="showPages(3)">3</a>
          </h2>
    
      
      
    
<h2>
  <span style="float: left;">
    <a href="#" onclick="showPages(current - 1)">Previous</a>
  </span>

  <span style="float: right;">
    <a href="#" onclick="showPages(current + 1)">Next</a>
  </span>
</h2>
```

Here you go..

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Comment: Sure Sir. Editing :)

Comment: Oh... I guess I was staring at that code too much... Now it's obvious. I'd rather not say how long I've been stuck to that ><. Thank you a lot, Aagam.